# Using getelementbyid in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have a question about use the `getElementById` in php.

```
$tile = "<script>document.getElementById('selRow0').value</script>";
$height = "<script>document.getElementById('height0').value</script>";
$width = "<script>document.getElementById('width0').value</script>";
```

**Make a SQL query in php**

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("partition");
$query = "SELECT `Price` FROM `database` WHERE `Material ID` IN (SELECT `Material_ID` FROM `material` WHERE `Tile` = '$tile') AND  `Width_Height ID` IN (SELECT `Width_Height ID` FROM `width_height` WHERE `Width` ='$width' AND `Height` ='$height');";
```

It doesn't run the code, why?

Comment: you are a little bit confused about php and javascript

Comment: `getElementById` is a javascript method

Comment: can you provide HTML code also.

Comment: @NileshSothiya Why would he? How you would use it? His HTML is completly irrelevant here.

Comment: @Ultra he can not use script like this, he need to post form to get value.

Comment: You need to pass the information collected by JavaScript to PHP using form post or AJAX.

Comment: As tinybyte said, you are mixing..., Cookies, or AJAX could be possible solutions

Comment: anyone have a good suggest?

Comment: @user3422462 You obviously do not understand some things. I would suggest that you use some time on learning PHP and Javascript (the difference between them, at least) before continuing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are mixing 2 separate languages.

To select DOM elements with PHP use [DOMDocument Class](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: JavaScript use the DOM, php can use it????

Comment: He is not thinking about the DOM. He wants to get some information from the browser to the server; parsing the DOM will not help with that.

Comment: It's so cool to have -2 and still its good answer.